# How to load specified variables from a mat file

Tags: matlab, mat-file

I have some mat files with large number of variables saved in it. So I only want to load a subset of the variables. For example, if I want to load

```
vars = {'x', 'y', 'z'}
```

I know I can explicitly do

```
a = load('filename.mat', 'x', 'y', 'z')
```

but the `vars` list can get long and I need to load multiple files, so I can't explicitly list out `vars` list every time. Is there a way to pass in `vars` as a argument input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass your cell array of variable names as a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) like so:

```
a = load('filename.mat', vars{:});
```